# Html Email doesn't display in iPhone mail until 'download full message' selected

Tags: html, ios, iphone, html-email

I have an email based reports, which have various embedded images and tables.

All display fine on iPhone.  However, once they get beyond a certain (quite limited) size, they display as raw text.

To view the email properly the user must scroll to the bottom and tap 'download full message' before it looks like it should.

Is there any way to encourage iOS to download the entire message so it displays as Html immediately?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a fix, it has to do with the number of characters before the closing </head> tag.

[Email on Acid - Ensure entire email is downloaded on the iOS device](http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C6/ensure_that_your_entire_email_is_rendered_by_default_in_the_iphone_ipad)

Very odd bug but EOA appears to have found a solid fix.

Answer (score 4):

I played around with this - on a 3G network, and on Wifi, with different size emails. My conclusion - it's not a fixed size limit, but something a bit more intelligent.

iOS detects your current network speed, the speed of the server from which any resources are being served and calculates the total size of the email.

If it thinks rendering the email is going to take what it considers a long time (I haven't been able to work out an exact number), then it gives you that message.

So how do you encourage iOS to display the whole email?

- Short messages, more text, fewer images
- Images compressed as much as possible, and served from a quick server (ideally a geocached CDN)

Look into media queries for how you can do some eye grabbing stuff on iOS without needing to send massive images.

Answer (score 3):

On Quora it's suggested this is a 50Kb limit , although I'd like to test that:

http://www.quora.com/iOS/Why-do-some-email-messages-on-an-iPhone-come-in-Partially-Downloaded

No mention of whether it can be controlled by the email that's being received, I think it's unlikely.

There's also a discussion about this on the Apple Support Communities, which doesn't seem to come to a resolution:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3091812

Comment: Thanks for that alecrust.  Yes, I'd seen that apple discussion also.  Not very conclusive!  :)